# same return variable for different functions

Tags: javascript

I have lots of functions which is used for validations. Can I use same return varibale for all the functions?

```
function fn1() {
    if () {..
        first = true;
    } else {
        first = false;
    }
    return first;
}

function fn2() {
    if () {..
        second = true;
    } else {
        second = false;
    }
    return second;
}

function fn3() {
    if () {..
        three = true;
    } else {
        three = false;
    }
    return three;
}


$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    var returnVal = true;
    returnVal1 = fn1();
    returnVal2 = fn2();
    returnVal3 = fn3();

    if (returnVal1 && returnVal2 && returnVal3) {
        returnVal = true;
    } else {
        returnVal = false;
    }
    return returnVal;
});
```

Instead of these many variables like `returnVal1`, `returnVal2` and `returnVal3`, can I use `returnVal` for all the function returns?
Can I use a single variable for all the function returns?

Thanks

Comment: Just call one function? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: You can return true/false from your function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, but if you want a single end variable that determines if any single one fails then I would recommend doing so like this:

```
var isValid = first();
if(!second())
    isValid = false;
if(!three())
    isValid = false;
```

That way you don't end up resetting an invalid flag with a subsequent result.

The benefits of this, is that if you have a lot of validation functions you can throw them into an array and write less code...

```
var validators = [first, second, three];//etc..
var isValid = true;
for(var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++){
    if(!validators[i]()){
        isValid = false;
        break;
    }
}
//do something with isValid
```

Or if you have a dedicated "validate all" function...

```
var validators = [first, second, three];
function validateAll(){
    for(var i = 0; i < validators.length; i++){
        if(!validators[i]()){ 
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Yes..I have lots of validation functions..So in the first case..U mean I have to call all the functions inside and array? like var validators = [fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4]

Comment: @user1049057: Not call them inside the array, just declare them. But your example is correct: `var validators = [fn1, fn2, fn3, fn4];` will work fine, but I guess you already know that based on you having accepted my answer

Answer (score 4):

You can drop the variables all together and just call your validation functions inside the `if` clause:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    if ( first() && second() && third() ) {
       return true;
    } else {
       return false;
    }
});
```

or shorter as @FishBasketGordo suggested, if the return value is the only thing you need:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    return first() && second() && third();
});
```

If the validation is rather computation heavy, this also saves you some time, as the `if`-clause is evaluated lazely.

Comment: Or just `return first() && second() && third();`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the last function by the following code

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    return (first() && second() && third());
});
```

Comment: Damn thanks for the heads up @Sirko, bad copy/paste, heading to the coffee machine right now

Answer (score 1):

If your returnValues are primitives that are going to be combined, you can easily combine their assignments. In your code snippet you can write it as below if you'd prefer:

```
$('#submitButton').click(function () {
    var returnVal = first() && second() && third();

    return !!returnVal; //ensure boolean is returned
});
```

Comment: I tried if(first && second && three){returnVal = true;}else{returnVal = false;}..But that doesnt seem to be working..

Comment: @user1049057 first second and three are functions. You have to call them

Comment: I mean the return variables of those function first, second and three..I am trying to put the return variables of those function inside if condition and checking

Comment: Make sure you dont have name conflicts with your variable names and functions. If you want to update your question I'll update this answer

Comment: yes..return variables and the function names are different. I just created this as a sample

Comment: @user1049057 The variables in `fn1` `fn2` and `fn3` are undefined and your if statement is not formatted correctly

Answer (score 0):

```
function validateFunction(){   
  var result;     
  // First Function Condition\
  if(First Function)
      { 
        result = true;
      else
        result = false;
      }
      checkTruFalse(result);

  // Second Function Condition
  if(Second Function)
      { 
        result = true;
      else
        result = false;
      }
      checkTruFalse(result);

   // Third Function Condition
   if(Third Function)
       { 
         result = true;
       else
         result = false;
       }
       checkTruFalse(result); 
   }
 }

 function checkTruFalse(result)
   {   
     if (result == false ){ alert('ERROR'); break; } 
   }

 $('#submitButton').click(function(){ validateFunction(); });
```

As per the situation you can pass another variable inside checkTruFalse function to set alert message about specific error.

```
function checkTruFalse(result, message ){
  alert('ERROR :: '+message);
}

checkTruFalse( result, 'Invalid Input for Numeric Value');
```